# make MacOS App Switcher (Cmd + Tab) remember last-used window?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

I want the macos App Switcher (cmd + tab) to always take me back to the most recently used window of the selected app, ***regardless of what desktop / space / monitor it's on.***

Is this possible?

Comment: It will if all windows are in the same space, if not it won't. You're fighting's paradigm, spaces is not designed to work with apps on more than one space.  I'd try thinking the other way round. Key command to a space, not to an app. That way that last used will be chosen by default.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense now why it is the default behavior, and that led me to the solution: unchecking the "displays have separate spaces" option in mission control.

Answer (score 1):

You can access "App Exposé" by pressing the up or down arrow key when hovering over the desired app in the App Switcher.  This will show a thumbnail of all the app's open windows in different spaces, then either click on the desired window or use the arrow keys to navigate to the desired window.
see [Unlock the Full Power of the macOS App Switcher](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/unlock-the-full-power-of-the-macos-app-switcher/)